# Submit clicks does not response when use AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am writing an HTML code, in which i am trying to use AJAX but whenever i do tap on Submit button nothing seems work for me.

But without using AJAX in my code, my form works just fine, so what could be the reason, see below HTML code (with AJAX) which is not working:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function () {

        $('form').on('submit', function (e) {

          e.preventDefault();

          $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: 'http://www.domain.com/offers/api.php',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function () {
              alert('form was submitted');
            }
          });

        });

      });
    </script>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form>
<input type="text" name="fname" />
<input type="text" name="lname" />
<input type="hidden" name="uname" value="amit" />
<input type="hidden" name="ukey" value="suri" />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is my old HTML Script, which was working perfectly:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form method="get" action="http://www.domain.com/offers/api.php" >
<input type="text" name="fname" />
<input type="text" name="lname" />
<input type="hidden" name="uname" value="amit" />
<input type="hidden" name="ukey" value="suri" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by *nothing seems to work*? Shouldn't your ajax call be a POST instead of a GET?

Comment: I mean i am not able to send data into database .....

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice you were setting the method to "get" in the regular form. So it looks like the cross origin request issue pointed by Ipg

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is the problem:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows
reading the remote resource at [url].
This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.
```

Same Origin Policy explained: http://www.jquery-tutorial.net/ajax/same-origin-policy/

Possible workaround: http://blog.edwards-research.com/2012/10/cross-domain-ajax-a-simple-workaround/

Comment: Actually I want form submission (can submit data to an external database) without page reloading or refreshing, so that I used AJAX. Is it possible using JSON too? If yes, How??????